# MFC can't find GetDocument() in a Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm new to MFC,and I want to get some data in a Dialog,but this doesn't work,

```
CTestDoc* pDoc=GetDocument();
pDoc->Get(...);
```

I Google it and find GetDocument() only used in CView.
So I try this and it really works:

```
CMainFrame *pMain=(CMainFrame *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd; 
CTestView *pView=(CTestView *)pMain->GetActiveView();
m_name=pView->v_name;
```

But I don't think it's a good solution,so I want to know is there any functions to solve this?Thank you.

Comment: Is your dialog box modal? If it is, Jonathan Wood has the right answer. If it is modeless, then you should track the current view anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say anything about what the dialog does but it may be desirable to pass this data to the dialog, and not have the dialog access the document data directly. This helps keep your dialog more isolated and more likely to be usable in other programs.

I would look at the command where the dialog is displayed. Is it in the view? If so, then you can pass the document data that is needed by the dialog. If not, then the code you posted may still make sense. Either way, that's where you should locate the desired document information, and then pass it to the dialog.

I would avoid making your dialog directly aware of the document if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from dialog, first set the data, and then get it.

For example:

```
CString save;
filePath.GetWindowsText(save);

richBox1.AddString(save); // to display in another box
```